# Missing cors headers on firestore server, but only when i try upload photo

Tags: node.js, firebase

I initialize my app with cors like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

There is a firebase function to upload photo when I receive error while uploading photo on react app:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
    exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
    const BusBoy = require("busboy");
    const path = require("path");
    const os = require("os");
    const fs = require("fs");
  
    const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });
  
    let imageToBeUploaded = {};
    let imageFileName;
    // String for image token
    let generatedToken = uuid();
  
    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);
      if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong file type submitted" });
      }

      const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1];
      imageFileName = `${Math.round(
        Math.random() * 1000000000000
      ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`;
      const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
      imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });
    busboy.on("finish", () => {
      admin
        .storage()
        .bucket()
        .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
          resumable: false,
          metadata: {
            metadata: {
              contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype,
              //Generate token to be appended to imageUrl
              firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: generatedToken,
            },
          },
        })
        .then(() => {
          // Append token to url
          const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media&token=${genera}`;
          return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imageUrl });
        })
        .then(() => {
          return res.json({ message: "image uploaded successfully" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
        });
    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  };
```

However, a function to upload post works.

```
exports.postTweet = (req, res) => {
    res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
    if(req.method !== "POST"){
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Method not allowed'})
    }
    console.log(req.user)
    console.log(req.body)
    const newTweet = {
        content: req.body.content,
        user: req.user.handle,
        userImage: req.user.imageUrl,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        likeCount: 0,
        commentCount: 0
    };
    admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('tweets')
    .add(newTweet)
    .then(doc => {
        const resTweet = newTweet;
        resTweet.tweetId = doc.id;
        res.json(resTweet);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: `something went wrong`})
        console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Also got other POST functions that works, but only image upload doesn't work because of cors...
Any ideas why?

Routes:
For image:

```
app.post('/user/image', FBAuth, uploadImage);
```

For post:

```
app.post('/create-tweet', FBAuth, postTweet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong header. The correct header is called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //res.header("Access-Control-Origin", "*"); //<--- ERROR 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //<--- CORRECT
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I've corrected headers in app initialization, still doesn't work. Then I added res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }) into upload image function, and still doesn't work..

Comment: Still problem with cors

Comment: Access has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint (or console log) in the cors function to see if it's really hit? And please also show how you define the upload endpoint on the server (ie the definition of the function and how you add the endpoint to the router)

Comment: And I see, you are adding a customer callback function for setting the cors headers as well as the express cors middleware. Maybe those two don't play together. Remove one of them

Comment: In terms of cors headers  - i've set them in many variants, only in fuction, only as the cors middleware, and even both. It works for other POST functions but uploading image.

Comment: Can u describe please, how to check if function hits the cors? The route has been added above

Comment: Furthermore, when looking at the docs of BusBoy (I have never used this lib before), I don't see a `busboy.end()` anywhere, but every example has a `req.pipe(busboy);` which is missing in your code. Maybe this has something to do with it, because your other example doesn't seem to handle a file-upload. Set a breakpoint at every `res.xxx` and check if the correct headers are included before they are sent back to the client

Comment: Gonna check it, but doesn't it work in a way, that if function doesn't have an access to the server because of CORS then is not called at all? Shouldn't i get any HTTP Response error, for example 500?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but in general it works as following: The client sends a request to the server, the server handles that request, adds the cors headers and sends back the result. Then the BROWSER checks if CORS headers are required (ie you are posting to a different host) and present. And based on that check, JS is allowed to access the response or not. Ie the browser always receives the answer from the server. But based on clientside checks, access is either granted or not

Comment: You can also just add a `console.log(res.getHeaders());` to print the response headers in the console before returning the response to the client and check if it contains the required CORS headers

Comment: And check if the client sends a preflight OPTIONS request, and if that request is handled correctly on the server

Comment: That is a result of console.log(res.getHeaders());                                                         
api
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
8:30:36.807 AM
api
'access-control-allow-headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' }

Comment: As i can see, preflight options are only PUT and DELETE, didn't see POST there, however, i edit the image so PUT should be ok

Comment: After initialazing function as app.put('/user/image', FBAuth, uploadImage) instead of post, and also changing axios.post to axios.put it gives me 404 error.

Comment: There is something seriously off in you app. But the error is not in the code you have posted. If an incoming request goes through both, your cors middleware and then your upload handler, it will have the necessary headers, unless some other part of the code you are not showing us manipulates the response. Set breakpoints in the server and check the results by stepping through ...

Comment: Ok, I've written all the functions once again, and the error is gone. However, I still don't know what is the case. Thanks, @derpirscher for all the help.

Comment: Moreover, it had to be something with the server functions - the photo upload didn't even work at localhost via postman.